# Fullcalendar display issue loading events and selectability

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, gcal

What I am trying to accomplish is to have use [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) to load in events from a Google calendar but only showing the days of that month and the days that do not have a scheduled event. These available days are then clicked on to bring up a contact form.

Issues

1. When changing months there is a flutter as events are loaded in from a Google calendar. Is there a way to load the events then show each month; or maybe there a way to avoid putting a mask (highlighted in blue) to cover up the day altogether and indicate that if there is an event, to make that day not visible?
2. In addition to events and days from other months not being visible, is there a way to make them not click-able too? Notice how clicking outside of the blue box also brings up a modal.

Here is what I have so far - http://jsfiddle.net/AzmJv/151/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    events: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
    eventClick: function (event) {
        return false;
    },
    editable: false,
    selectable: true,
    //header and other values
    select: function (date, allDay) {
        date = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dddd dd MMMM yyyy');

        var mywhen = date;

        $('#createEventModal #apptAllDay').val(allDay);
        $('#createEventModal #when').text(mywhen);
        $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
    }
});

$('#submitButton').on('click', function (e) {
    // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
    e.preventDefault();

    doSubmit();
});

function doSubmit() {
    $("#createEventModal").modal('hide');
    console.log($('#apptStartTime').val());
    console.log($('#apptEndTime').val());
    console.log($('#apptAllDay').val());
    alert("form submitted");

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
        title: $('#patientName').val(),
        start: new Date($('#apptStartTime').val()),
        end: new Date($('#apptEndTime').val()),
        allDay: ($('#apptAllDay').val() == "true"),
    },
    true);
}
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Also any suggestions on a better title are appreciated

Comment: All your events are fetched from a google calendar?

Comment: Yes, there will be one Google calendar for all the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the presence of and event using [`clientEvents`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/):

> Retrieves events that FullCalendar has in memory.

and if there are any stop your function.

Code:

```
select: function (date, allDay) {

            var dayEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {
                return event.start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) === date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            });

            if (dayEvents.length>0) return

            date = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dddd dd MMMM yyyy');

            var mywhen = date;

            $('#createEventModal #apptAllDay').val(allDay);
            $('#createEventModal #when').text(mywhen);
            $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
```

You can style the presence of an event using:

```
.fc-event-skin {
    border: 1px dotted red !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: black;    
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/gmm8b/1/

Comment: That seems to be working. Can the days from next/previous months (in gray) also be targeted to be unclickable. The flutter of events loading is still present. When the user advances months, can the events with the applied background load at the same time as the rest of the calendar so you don't see the number of the event dates at all - http://jsfiddle.net/gmm8b/3/

Comment: @NewbCake you can check if the selected date is in the current month, if don't exit the function (when I can I provide an example)

Comment: Thank you! To my amazement I managed to get, with your guiding direction, something that works. Would you please look of the code and see if there is a better way of writing this? http://jsfiddle.net/gmm8b/6/  Also the main problem of when clicking next/prev showing the dates then disappearing; is the way to prevent that from happening maybe waiting until the Google event info loads then rendering the whole thing at the same time?

Comment: @NewbCake The code it's ok! You can accept the answer; for the refresh/fetching data in change month I think it can be done with a change on the plugin, but I have to check it (can be long) but for now it's working as requested right?